# Highcharts markers on line only where there are labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have successfully labeled a time series for a subset of the points (where the time is either 3am or 3pm), but now to make the chart look cleaner I would like to only have the markers show up at the points where there are labels. Anyone out there know how to accomplish this? I am trying to add a graphic.destroy command in the label but I can't seem to get it to work.

js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abbike18/z2k8h/1/

```
    dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            y: -10,
            formatter: function() {
                if(Highcharts.dateFormat('%l',this.x) == '3')
                    {return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0, '.');}
                //else{data.graphic.destroy();}
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this.point.destroy()` function

http://jsfiddle.net/z2k8h/2/

Comment: I like this solution, although it does not seem to continue to work if you do something that has a chart.redraw(). Maybe because the points have already been destroyed and it tries to re-destroy them?

Comment: what about another if statement in the else statement with something like `if(this.point.exisits){this.point.destroy()}`?

Comment: Try to use hide() function